# How to resolve the conflict in impl-trait-for-tuple version | nicks pallet tutorial

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

I am following the tutorial on substrate playground, and when I run the cargo check, I get the following compilation error:

```
 error: failed to select a version for `impl-trait-for-tuples`.
    ... required by package `frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.20#563f4820)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-support` of package `pallet-nicks v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.20#563f4820)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `pallet-nicks` of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/playground/workspace/runtime)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/playground/workspace/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.2.2` are: 0.2.2

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `impl-trait-for-tuples v0.2.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `impl-trait-for-tuples = "^0.2.1"` (locked to 0.2.1) of package `frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=devhub/latest#e6fbbd5c)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-support` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `frame-benchmarking v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=devhub/latest#e6fbbd5c)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `frame-benchmarking-cli v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=devhub/latest#e6fbbd5c)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking-cli` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/playground/workspace/node)`

failed to select a version for `impl-trait-for-tuples` which could resolve this conflict how to solve this issue?
```

Comment: Your issue is on cargo.toml and can you try to clean cache ( cargo clean). If it doesnt work try to check careful your dependecies

Answer (score 1):

I just ran the [substrate playground](https://playground.substrate.dev/) and the version that is in the Cargo.lock file is:

```
[[package]]
name = "impl-trait-for-tuples"
version = "0.2.2"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "11d7a9f6330b71fea57921c9b61c47ee6e84f72d394754eff6163ae67e7395eb"
dependencies = [
 "proc-macro2",
 "quote",
 "syn",
]
```

If you're still running into this issue, delete your Cargo.lock file and re-run cargo build.